# Java 9 processing list of objects with nullable fields into another list

Tags: java, list, collections, java-stream

I have a list of objects like

```java
@Getter
@Setter
public class Person {
    private String name;
    private boolean value_bool;
    private String value_string;
    private Integer value_integer;
    private String value_text;
}
```

The problem is, only ONE of these fields (except for name) is actually initiated (e.g. non-null) for one Person, every other one is null, so for 4 of these values there are 4 Person instances each having a name and one of the values. How do I transform this list of Person objects into a list of value objects, preferably using streamAPI?

Comment: i don't understand your intend. Do you have a list of person-objects and want a list of strings (with the names of the persons)?

Comment: I have a list of person-objects and I want a list of values (or a map of values, each value mapped to a name)

Comment: Could you provide some examples? What exactly is the type of the result? `List<Value>`?

Comment: I have a list of Persons, each person having a name and one of the 4 fields, say Value<?> (it's a pojo to be used in json). Value has a key (which is Person's name) and a value, which is one of Person's fields

Answer (score 0):

The `boolean value_bool` cannot be `null`.

To merge this data, first you'd want to group by `name`, and then collapse a `List<Person>` (which would represent the separate Person objects all with the same name) into a single merged Person.

To group:

```
Map<String, List<Person>> grouped = persons.stream()
.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Person::getName));
```

Merging a `List<Person>` into a single Person is not particularly suitable to stream-based code. I would just make a method, it's a little complicated as you have lots of non-obvious choices to make. For example, let's say you have 2 with `value_bool` is false, and 1 with `true`. And 2 Person objects both have a non-null `value_string`, and they aren't the same string; which one wins, or should an exception be thrown, or should the strings be concatenated?

The fact that such questions exist, and have no obvious answers, should strongly indicate that there is no simple one-liner that could possibly do this.

Thus, something like:

```
public class Person {
 // ....
  public static Person merge(@NonNull Collection<? extends Person> persons) {
    if (persons.isEmpty()) throw new IllegalArgumentException(
      "Cannot merge an empty list of persons");
    if (persons.size() == 1) return persons.iterator().next();
    Person out = null;
    for (Person person : persons) {
        if (out == null) {
          out = person;
          continue;
        }
        // If any part-person is 'valueBool', the output is also.
        if (person.isValueBool()) out.setValueBool(true);
        // For the rest, the 'last' non-null value 'wins':
        if (person.getValueString() != null) out.setValueString(person.getValueString());
        // etc
    }
    return out;
  }
}
```

armed with that method:

```
persons.stream()
  .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Person::getName))
  .values()
  .stream()
  .map(Person::merge)
  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Where that last line can be `toList();` if  you have JDK16.

Comment: This is kind of what I came up with in the first place; however if a person's value_bool is true (or value_string is not null etc) then it is guaranteed that the other fields are null (or false in case of value_bool) with only exception being name, which always has a value; so I thought maybe there is a way to one-line that